# Triple integrals(calculating volume)

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, volume

I want to check whether I am working this example correctly. I need to find volume of surface bounded with $y^2+z^2\le 2y,\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\le x, x\le 6-y^2-z^2$. First I graphed this in 3D. All of three given surfaces are located on x-axis. First one is inside of cylinder, second outside of upper cone, and third one paraboloid but only its inner part. So we have that the projection on YZ plane is the circle with radius 1, and center $(1,0)$. So i can use triple integrals to calculate the volume(and polar coordinates) so I get that $0\le r\le 2\cos\phi, -\frac{\pi}{2}\le\phi\le\frac{\pi}{2},
r\le x\le 6-r^2$. And what is left is to plug this in formula $V=\iiint dxdydz$. Is my working correct?
Thank you.

Comment: You should either switch to cylindrical coordinates, and then the formula for volume is different, or stay in Cartesian coordinates. In either case, you need to **explicitly** find the limits of integration. Note that you have several inequalities involving $r$.

Comment: Typing mistake, I meant $r\le x\le 6-r^2$, did you meant that(now it is all in cylindrical coordinates).

Comment: Yes. Now the limits are fine for cylindrical coordinates. You need to write $V$ in these coordinates as well.

Comment: Ok, ok. Everything else is fine right?

Comment: In your $3D$ sketch, did you notice what happens at $x = 2$? Seems to be the value of $x$ where cone comes out of the cylinder and also that is where cone and paraboloid intersect. Also it is not correct that the second one is outside the cone. It is inside the cone.

Comment: Yep, somehow misunderstood that, thanks a lot. Everything else is ok?

Comment: Yes yes, the integral set-up looks fine. My comment was only on the interpretation.